# Need help resolving SSPI error message in SSMS after changing owner of SQL service

Tags: ssms, sspi

I recently had to change the owners of the SQL Server and SQL agent services.  Windows Server 2016 OS and SQL Server 2016 Std Edition.  The server in question hosts 6 instances and after changing the owner of the 2 services for all instances one of them has problems connecting to one or more applications and generates the following error message with attempting to access via SSMS.
"The target principle name is incorrect. Cannot generate the SSPI context"
I changed the service owner back to the previous ones just for this one instance.  All other instances are running with the new owners without issue.
From my research it appears to be an SPN related error, but not sure how to diagnose or fix for just one instance.